# Does an added class in jQuery carry over after page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remember which tabs were open in my menu after reload. Here's my js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sidebar div").hide();
    $(".sidebar li a").click(function () {
//        alert($(this).attr("class"));
        var myClass=$(this).attr("class");

        if ($("#div"+myClass).attr("class")!='active') {
            $("#div"+myClass).slideToggle();        //open tab
            $("#div"+myClass).addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $("#div"+myClass).slideToggle();        //close tab
            $("#div"+myClass).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

It's constantly adding and taking away the class "active" each time I click on it. I also have this right below it:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".active").slideToggle();
});
```

Whenever I reload my page, even when a couple of tabs have an `active` class, they do not appear to be slideToggling. Am I doing this wrong? Is there an easy way around this?

Comment: If you want persistent storage across requests you'll need to use [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: *"Does an added class in jQuery carry over after page reload?"* - No. (And as an aside, it's better to use .hasClass('active') to test whether your element has the class, because testing  .attr('class')!='active' works only as long as the element can't possibly have any additional classes.)

Comment: Thank you both vanneto and nnnnnn